# How to render html dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have data like:

`&lt;p&gt;50 Roses in a Heart Shape&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 15px;&quot;&gt;; Make your recipient the princess of the day with this lovely and luxurious bouquet.&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\u000d\u000a`

which i want to append to my div dynamically from jquery. How do I do that?

Here is what I am doing:

```
var param = '{"CategoryId":72}';
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url : serviceUrl,
            dataType:"json",
            data:param,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success : function (msg) {

            $.each(msg, function(index, table) {
            var data=' <div class="ui-block-c">';
            data+=' <div class="ui-body ui-body-d">';
            data+=' <h4>'+table.Name+'</h4>';
            data+=' <p>';
            data+= table.Description;
            data+='</p>';
            data+=' <img src="img/pink coral roses.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">';
            data+=' <p>'+table.Price+'</p>';
            data+=' <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Add To Cart</button>';
            data+=' </div>';
            data+=' </div>';
            alert(data);
            $('.mainGrid').append(data);

      });
            },
            error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error in LoadLayout');

            }
    });
```

Here `table.Description` returns the string I mention on top and `.mainGrid` is the class of the div I want to append data to. My above code does not render the string as Html. How do I do that?

Comment: did you try doing  `$('.mainGrid').html(data);` ?

Comment: This is working for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/xj4xhfg7/6/. You should check console error.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I am getting data from webservice, table.description and table.name aren't the data I want to print

Comment: Okay, backup.  Have you tried doing the append() with a simple piece of text in it?  If that works, then your problem isn't with append(), it's with the data you've got.  Try doing  `$('.mainGrid').append("text");` and see if it works, that will let you isolate the problem.

Comment: Yes It is working with simple text.

Comment: Yeah that i used as string because `table` variable is not available with me. But you can check in console log if there is any error because of `table` variable has all values then it should work as it is.

Comment: are you sure your `table` variable holds what you think it does?  If you do console.log(table) within the loop, does it print what it should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get jQuery to compile it for you, then append it.

```
var div = $('<div class="ui-block-c">');
var data = $('<div class="ui-body ui-body-d">');
data.append('<h4>' + table.Name + '</h4>');
var description = ($('<div>').append(table.Description)).text();
data.append(description);
data.append('<img src="img/pink coral roses.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">');
data.append('<p>' + table.Price + '</p>');
data.append('<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Add To Cart</button>');
div.append(data);
$('.mainGrid').append(div);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4z1nm7o/1/

Answer (score 1):

Although the way you are doing it is considered a bad practice as too much of text concatenation of html smells bad code. 
You have to unescape it and make it look like html by getting the nodeValue
according to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700369/986160

```
var encoded = "&lt;span&gt;test&lt;/span&gt;"; // or your data
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = encoded;
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
$('.mainGrid').append(decoded);
```